# Double integral with parametrization

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate $$\int\int_D(-2x^2+2xy+1)\,dx\,dy $$ where

$$D: x^2+y^2≤a^2$$

I have parametrized as follows:

$$x=a\cos t$$
$$y=a\sin t$$

$$\int_0 \int_0^a(-2a^2cos^2t+2a^2\cos t\sin t+1)r\,dr\,dt $$

$$ 0<r<a, 0<t<2\pi$$

I keep getting the wrong answer. Was hoping someone could tell me if my parametrization is wrong. Thanks

Comment: Maybe the domain is really $x^2+y^2 \le a^2,$ which would be two dimensional and so match the $dxdy$ in the integral.

Comment: Yes it is sorry my mistake!

Comment: How would you complete the square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use polar, try $x=r \cos t,y=r\sin t$ (don't stick an $a$ in there). So the $a$'s inside your version should be replaced by $r$, and use the limits $r$ from $0$ to $a$ and $t$ from $0$ to $2\pi.$

Comment: Why shouldn't there be an a?

Comment: The $a$ just tells the boundary of the region, and is not part of a variable point *inside* the region. So $a$ should only appear in the integration limits.

Comment: Yes, once everything in the integrated function is put in terms of $r$ and $t$ (there winds up being a factor of $r^3$ because of the area element $rdrdt$) it should give the correct value, since only the trig part remains, and the region has become such that the $r^3$ integral can be done separately and then multiplied by the integral of the remaining trig part.